# how to add generic background service

Tags: asp.net-core

How do you add generic background service in asp.NET 2.2?

```
public class TestBackgroundService<T> : BackgroundService
{
    private ICustomClass<T> _customClass = new CustomClass<T>();

    public TestBackgroundService(ICustomClass<T> customClass)
    {
        _customClass = customClass;
    }
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class CustomClass<T> : ICustomClass<T>
{
}

public interface ICustomClass<T>
{
}

public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(ICustomClass<>), typeof(CustomClass<>));
        services.AddHostedService<TestBackgroundService<>>(); // THIS LINE DOESN'T COMPILE

    }

}
```

Comment: Habe you had any success on this? I am having the same requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You should ask yourself what a generic background service should even do? If you don’t specify a `T`, then how is it supposed to work?

Generic classes without a specified type argument are just “templates” of classes and cannot be instantiated. You have to understand that only by specifying a type argument, a generic type actually becomes a concrete type that can be used and instantiated. That also means that there is an *infinite* amount of potential types that originate from generic types.

So when you think about the background service, what type argument should the framework choose for you? *All* of them? Then there would be an infinite amount of background services and the application could never start. Or just *some* of them? In that case it would be up to *you* to specify which concrete type arguments you want to use and register each of those background services separately.

Comment: is the answer based on the current version of the question?

Comment: @monty Yes. You cannot register a generic background service without specifying actual type arguments for the reasons outlined in my answer.