# Handle generic types in GetMethod

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

What would be the correct arguments for GetMethod in the AddService(services, type, instance) exactly defining the generic version (just in case there will come more overloads).

I know I could just keep the method names different but I don't want to.

Currently I get either null or an exception due to multiple found method versions...

The code:

```
namespace Sample
{

    public interface IService { }

    public static class SampleExtensions
    {

        public static IServiceCollection AddService<T>(this IServiceCollection services, T instance) where T : IService
        {
            //services.AddSingleton<T>(instance);
            services.AddSingleton(instance.GetType(), instance); // register with the concrete implementation type
            //some stuff that only works with generic T
            return services;
        }

        public static IServiceCollection AddService(this IServiceCollection services, Type type, object instance)
        {

            Type classType = typeof(SampleExtensions);
            MethodInfo methodInfo = classType.GetMethod                         // correct arguments??
            (
                nameof(AddService),                                             // only name would bring 2 results
                new Type[] { typeof(IServiceCollection), typeof(object) }       // ??? instance is generic
            );
            MethodInfo genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type);
            genericMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { services, instance });           // call the generic method version
            return services;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: because IService instance would hide the concrete implementation type and make all calls being of type IService. I am working on exactly what he did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60587647/how-to-add-generic-background-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenericmethodparameter?view=net-5.0) to represent a generic parameter reference:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = classType.GetMethod                         
(
    nameof(AddService),                                             
    new Type[] { typeof(IServiceCollection), Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0) }      
);
```

Comment: In my case it doesn't work - to **Get** the `public static void AddLink<T0>(UnityAction<T0> unityAction, UnityEvent<T0> unityEvent) { }` **By** `myClassType.GetMethod("AddLink", new Type[] {Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0), Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0)}`

Comment: @DenisSivtsov that is because you have parameters not of type `T0` but `UnityAction<T0>` and `UnityEvent<T0>`